# Serve bathymetry layers on a map according to zoom level

Tags: postgis, polygon, layers, geometry

I have geometry type records in PostGIS database - arrays of water bodies coordinates and depths. I want to display water body polygons on the map. When a website loads up, it should show more abstract layers to avoid excessive loading and get more detailed ones while zooming in. What tools would recommend to use to serve water body layers according to zoom level? How to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an [OGC Web Map Service (WMS)](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms) or [OGC Web Map Tile Service (WMTS)](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wmts).  This would give you queryable images of your data, that change as you zoom in.  If you want vector data presented to your client then you'd want an [OGC Web Feature Service (WFS)](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs)

There's various software that can help you set up such services, such as the Free/Open source [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/uk/) or [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/), both work well with PostGIS.

Once you've set up your services you'd probably want to use a JavaScript library such as [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/) or [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) to provide you web map and call your data through the services.

But you'd also be able to use your services in desktop clients such as [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/)

There are plenty of questions on GIS.SE that will help with any issues you have moving forward, and the documentation for all the software listed here is good too.